# Free app for playing movies with subtitle

Tags: windows-10-mobile, apps

Is there a good free movie player (MP4), which can display subtitle on windows phone 10 ? If there is no free one, what player do you suggest me to buy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quickly tested the following free apps with video files in both MP4 and MKV formats:

- [Films & TV](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/p/films-tv/9wzdncrfj3p2) (built-in) - didn't seem to support subtitles in MP4 files, though it may have just been the particular file I tested with (I only have a couple of MP4 files with subs). MKV worked fine, though.
- [VLC for Windows Phone](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/p/vlc-for-windows-phone/9wzdncrcv5tl) - both MP4 and MKV formats seemed to work fine, though the app itself is a bit buggy (often crashing or hanging on certain actions).
- [CCPLayer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/p/ccplayer/9wzdncrfjljx) (and the [UWP version](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/p/ccplayer-uwp-ad/9nblggh4z7q0)) - both MP4 and MKV formats worked fine. The UWP version has, in my opinion, a better UI, supports playing videos from network shares, and there's also a [paid version](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/p/ccplayer-pro/9wzdncrfjljw) that doesn't have ads.

Overall CCPlayer would seem to be the best option, but feel free to install all of those apps and see which one works best with the video files you have.

Comment: Thanks for this usefull answer, CCPlayer works well in my WP.